# Firebase: push multi child data using function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to save data to firebase multi child node:

```
--Events
----Races
-------Participants
```

Here is a dummy data, This a type of data that I want to save to firebase

```
  var dummyData = [

            {
                event_id: 1,
                event_venue: "Churchill Ground Venue",
                event_name: "Victoria Cup",
                event_type: "Holiday Special",
                event_datetime: now,
                event_url: 'www',
                races: {
                    1: {
                        race_id: 1,
                        race_type: "Horse Race",
                        race_url: "www",
                        race_name: "Super Hourse 8",
                        race_venue: "Ground No 7",
                        race_datetime: now,
                        races_participants: {
                            1: {
                                participants_id: 1211,
                                participants_name: "Doll Fire",
                                participants_place_odds: 10,
                                participants_win_odds: 5,
                                participants_result: 0,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    2: {
                        race_id: 2,
                        race_type: "Horse Race 2",
                        race_url: "www",
                        race_name: "Super Hourse 9",
                        race_venue: "Ground No 7",
                        race_datetime: now,
                        races_participants: {
                            participants_id: {
                                participants_id: 222,
                                participants_name: "Doll Fire 2",
                                participants_place_odds: 130,
                                participants_win_odds: 54,
                                participants_result: 03,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        ];

 //calling Services to post data
  EventsFactory.postEvents(dummyData[0]);

  myApp.factory('EventsFactory', function(){
    var factiry = {};
     //post data to fb server
    factory.postEvents = function (data) {
        //passed data must be object
        var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://api.firebaseio.com/");

        firebaseRef.child("events").push({
            event_id: data.event_id,
            event_venue: data.event_venue,
            event_name: data.event_name,
            event_type: data.event_type,
            event_url: data.event_url,
            event_datetime: data.event_datetime,
            races: {
              //not sure how to store multiple child, Cant call for each to loop 
              //each paased object from data var
                race_id: {
                    race_id: data.races.race_id,
                    race_type: data.races.race_type,
                    race_url: data.races.race_url,
                    race_name: data.races.race_name,
                    race_venue: data.races.race_venue,
                    race_datetime: data.races.race_datetime,
                    races_participants: {
                        participants_id: {
                            participants_id: data.races.races_participants.participants_id,
                            participants_name: data.races.races_participants.participants_name,
                            participants_place_odds: data.races.races_participants.participants_place_odds,
                            participants_win_odds: data.races.races_participants.participants_win_odds,
                            participants_result: data.races.races_participants.participants_result
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    }
    return factory;
  });
```

My Question is: Why push is not storing data array and pushing it to Firebase(including all child elements)

currently I am getting: Cannot read property 'participants_id' of undefined
    at Object.factory.postEvents 
But I have all the values in data array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply push the entire event to Firebase in one big push.

```
firebaseRef.child("events").push(data); // bad practice, don't do this!
```

But that means you'll end up using array indices for child nodes on the server. Array indices are notoriously likely to cause problems in distributed data structures. So whenever you have a list-like structure, it is best to simply `push` each item into Firebase and let them generate a unique ID for you.

For your case that means that you need to loop-and-push for each `event` (only one in the example), `race` and `participant`.

Code sample:

```
    // Add the event
    var event = firebaseRef.child("events").push({
        event_id: data.event_id,
        event_venue: data.event_venue,
        event_name: data.event_name,
        event_type: data.event_type,
        event_url: data.event_url,
        event_datetime: data.event_datetime
    });

    // Add then races to the event
    data.races.forEach(function(race) {
        var race = event.child("races").push({
            race_id: race.race_id,
            race_type: race.race_type,
            race_url: race.race_url,
            race_name: race.race_name,
            race_venue: race.race_venue,
            race_datetime: race.race_datetime,
        });

        // Add the participants to the race
        race.race_participants.forEach(function(participant) {
            race.child("participants").push({
                participants_id: participant.participants_id,
                participants_name: participant.participants_name,
                participants_place_odds: participant.participants_place_odds,
                participants_win_odds: participant.participants_win_odds,
                participants_result: participant.participants_result

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Isn't this a poor design because if you ever want to just fetch the basic "event" information you will ultimately fetch everything nested "BELOW" the parent node. Not saying that your question doesn't answer the person's original inquiry, but this is a bit of an anti-pattern for structuring data when the amount of items below any particular node could become large. You could end up retrieving 5000 participants just to get basic info about events/races. This is a good article discussing some of these concepts. https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data